# Angular 14: Unchecking checkbox display empty array instead of unfiltered list

Tags: angular

So I have a `selectionChange` that filters a list upon selecting a checkbox, but when the user unselects the checkbox, the list does not return to its unfiltered state, it returns an empty array and I am not sure how to fix that the Angular way.

I have a method on that checkbox list called `onChangeContinentCheckBox()`

```
onChangeContinentCheckBox() {
 this.filteredCountries = this.countries.filter((country: ICountry) => {
   return this.selectedContinents.value?.includes(country.continent);
 });
}
```

Which is applied in the template with a `selectionChange`, but there is another method that matches between the key of the continents json file to the value of the property of countries json file.

```
getContinents() {
 Object.keys(this.continents as IContinents).forEach((key) => {
  this.continentsObj.push({
   name: this.continents[key],
   code: key
  });
 });
}
```

And that `getContinents()` gets passed into `ngOnInit()` and this is how its being applied in the template file.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [formControl]="selectedContinents" placeholder="Filter by Continents" multiple (selectionChange)="onChangeContinentCheckBox()">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let continent of continentsObj" [value]="continent.code">{{continent.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I am thinking something like:

```
onChangeContinentCheckBox() {
 this.filteredCountries = this.countries.filter((country: ICountry) => {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      return this.selectedContinents.value?.includes(country.continent);
    }
      return this.countries;
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you returning `this.countries` inside the `filter` method?
Your solution works because `this.countries` exists and resolves as truthy. You could as well replace it with `return true`.

Or you could try something like this instead:

```
onChangeContinentCheckBox() {
   this.filteredCountries = (this.selectedContinents.value?.length > 0) ?
      this.countries.filter((country: ICountry) => 
         this.selectedContinents.value?.includes(country.continent)) :
      [ ...this.countries ];
}
```

Comment: I will check it out. I also have a solution.

Comment: I went with your solution. Thank you.